# Slicing string character correctly in C++

Tags: c++

I'd like to count number `1` in my input, for example,`111` (1+1+1) must return `3`and
`101`must return `2` (1+1)
To achieve this,I developed sample code as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string S;
    cout<<"input number";
    cin>>S;
    cout<<"S[0]:"<<S[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"S[1]:"<<S[1]<<endl;
    cout<<"S[2]:"<<S[2]<<endl;
    int T = (int) (S[0]+S[1]+S[2]);
    cout<<"T:"<<T<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I execute this code I input `111` for example and my expected return is `3` but it returned `147`.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-187 atcoder]$ ./a.out
input number
111
S[0]:1
S[1]:1
S[2]:1
T:147
```

What is the wrong point of that ? I am totally novice, so that if someone has opinion,please let me know. Thanks

Comment: There is a difference between a number and a character. A digit is something 'in between'. You could either work the character route (see ASCII code or even Unicode/UTF-8) or read in a number and try to calculate mathematically the digits.

Comment: `std::count(S.begin(), S.end(), '1');`

Comment: As an alternative you can use `int result = std::count(S.begin(), S.end(), '1');` from `<algorithm>`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bGc6P3sxq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `S[0]` is a `char`. You are adding the character values of these digits, rather than the numerical value. In ASCII, numerical digits start at value 48. In other words, each of your 3 values are exactly 48 too big.

So instead of doing `1+1+1`, you're doing `49+49+49`.

The simplest way to convert from character value to digit is to subtract 48, which is the value of `0`.

e.g, `S[0] - '0'`.

Comment: But only, if you are sure that it is a digit and not a letter or other symbol. If the string contains a character consisting of multiple bytes (Unicode) the indexing will fail.

Comment: Absolutely; the code has no error/bounds checking, so big warning there.

Answer (score 4):

Since your goal is to count the occurrences of a character, it makes no sense to sum the characters together. I recommend this:

```
std::cout << std::ranges::count(S, '1');
```

---

To explain the output that you get, characters are integers whose values represent various symbols (and non-printable control characters). The value that represents the symbol `'1'` is not 1. `'1'+'1'+'1'` is not `'3'`.

Comment: This version works since `c++20`